# How do I read a whole file and make a list of the items in the file?

Tags: java

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
acorn squash 2365989335
alfalfa sprouts 3988549919
almond 9277904615
anchovy 3352461607
anise 0846115239
apple 7827295890
apricot 0662812477
artichoke 5974131818
asparagus 8485010646
```

it continues on for another couple hundred items. The list has the item name then the UPC right next to it, then a new line and it continues just like that.

I am supposed to read this file (foodUPC.txt) and put all of the items into a list for use later. I am stuck trying to put all of these items into a list. Later, I have to read all of the items a return an item based on its UPC. I also don't know how to do that.

Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Have you tried ... googling?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know how to read files?  Do you know how to create a list?

Comment: It is astonishing to me that this got 2 up-votes.  It is not clear what the OP needs help with, and there is no sign of research or effort.

Answer (score 2):

[BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html), [String.split(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) are what you want. I will let you put all these 3 together.

Answer (score 2):

I think the NIO API comes in handy for this as you can easily read all the lines from a file (seeing that your items are separated by newlines):

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines( Paths.get("foodUPC.txt"), Charset.forName( "MyCharset" ) /* or Charset.defaultCharset(), although this is not recommended for portable apps! */ );
for( String line : lines ) {
    String[] arr = line.split( " " );
    // here comes your code
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a hashmap-
upc code is the key and value is the name

to get the mapping - use regex to split the line

```
InputStream    inputStream;
BufferedReader buffreader;

HashMap<String, String> hm= new HashMap<String,String>();

inputStream= new FileInputStream("foodUPC.txt");
buffreader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
   String[] datas=line.split(" ");[if its a tab use \t]
hm.put(datas[0],datas[1]);
}
```

Use this map where ever u need.

Comment: This is homework. I think it is agreed that people should not provide full answers for questions like these.